# How unbind then bind again?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $('.imgc').hover(
    function(e) {                              
         $(this).effect("bounce", { times:5 }, "slow"); 

    },
   function(e) {  
   $(this).unbind('mouseenter');
});
```

I need to set an effect on the image. But I need this effect to work only at once. But then I need to bind again on mouseout. But it does not work.

```
('.imgc').bind('mouseenter', e);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: why dont you use http://api.jquery.com/on/ and http://api.jquery.com/off/ as `bind` and `unbind` are deprecated

Comment: i guess if you explain a little more what you are looking for, you shouldn't need to unbind event

Comment: Try http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$('.imgc').on('hover', function(e) {                              
         $(this).one(function () {
               $(this).effect("bounce", { times:5 }, "slow"); 
         });
        $(this).off('mouseenter');
    },
   function(e) {  
        $(this).on('mouseenter');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this,

```
$(".imgc").on({
   mouseenter:function(){
      $(this).effect("bounce", { times:5 }, "slow"); 
   },
   mouseleave:function(){
   }
});
```

**hover** is basically a pseudoevent, which maps to **mouseenter** and **mouseleave**.